# How to make a hover on just specific div inside div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a template using Bootstrap. I have a little problem with my CSS hover. I just make a hover on `div` inside `div`.

This fiddle show my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/iklas/q5Lm7cLe/

When I hover on thumbnail the hover is showing on all parent `div` product-box.

I want when I hover on product-box the hover showing on just thumbnail `div`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean? if you know a solution tell us if you not don't write any problem you have,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `position: relative;` to `.thumbnail`

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q5Lm7cLe/1/)

Answer (score 1):

When You hover on thumbnail the hover is showing on all parent beacause you haven't give the css property Position:relative to .thumbnail.

```css
.product-box a {
  color: #666;
}

.product-box a:hover {
  color: #666;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.thumbnail {
  position: relative;
}

.thumbnail:hover:before {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="product-box col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x250/bdbdbd/fff&text=image" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
          <h4 class="product-title">SheIn Grey Contrast Collar Long Sleeve Pleated Dress</h4>
          <h4 class="brand-name pull-left"><span>By</span> Day Dresses</h4>
          <h4 class="price-number pull-right">$34.56</h4>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-product -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me the reason why you down wrote my answer.

Comment: thank you so much is working now i forgot to add position relative ti .thumbnail, ho down your answer?

Comment: Use this 
.thumbnail:before {content: ""; transition: all 600ms linear 0s; }
.thumbnail:hover:before {background-color: #000;width: 100%;height: 100%;  display: block;  position: absolute;  content: "";  top: 0px;  right: ;
  bottom: 0;  left: 0;  margin: auto;  opacity: 0.5;  -webkit-transition: all 00ms ease;  -moz-transition: all 600ms ease;  -ms-transition: all 600ms ease;  -o-transition: all 600ms ease;  transition: all 600ms ease; }

Answer (score 0):

Your transition is not working because you haven't used this.
Try this is would work.

```
.thumbnail:before {
  content: "";
  transition: all 600ms linear 0s;
 }

.thumbnail:hover:before {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 600ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 600ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 600ms ease;
  transition: all 600ms ease;
 }
```